# Change entity's property "Nullable" property using data annotation and metadata class? Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 6 - Database-first, I created my model and classes from existing database, some columns are required and they are set by triggers in the database side, so they appear in the model with "Nullable=false", and whenever I update/add a row in the application it complains about these columns as required.

I tried using data annotation "DatabaseGenerateOption=Compute" in a metadata class , and assigned the metadata class to the entity class,  but it did not seem to override the nullable=false property.

Am I missing something here? any direction to achieve the required here?

**EDIT**
below is a compination between "DatabaseGenerateOption" and EdmScalerProperty", I have tired and did not work.

```
public class Entity1_Metadata
{
    [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = true, IsNullable = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty= false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string LAST_UPDT_BY { get; set; }

}
[MetadataType(typeof(Entity1_Metadata))]
public partial class Entity1 { }
```